# Switch first and last elements of an array Error

Tags: arrays, netbeans, switch-statement, element

For one of my methods, its role is to switch the first and last elements of an array. It worked just fine when I had the array built into the method. But then I decided to just have it read in an array from main and now it doesn't work right. It replaces different numbers each time or sometimes doesn't replace anything and just copies the array.
Examples:
20432
20432
and 
44413
44431 and
42203

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] array = new int[5];
   int length = array.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random () * 5); 
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    flipFirstAndLast(array);
    replaceEvenWithZero(array);// TODO code application logic here
}
public static void flipFirstAndLast(int[] array){

    int i = array[0];
    int j = array[array.length - 1];


     int hold = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j] ;
     array[j] =  hold;
     for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
         System.out.print(array[k]);
    }

     System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void flipFirstAndLast(int[] array){

    int i = array[0];
    int j = array[array.length - 1];


     int hold = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j] ;
     array[j] =  hold;
     for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
         System.out.print(array[k]);
    }
```

just copy this code you will get your answer i tried it and it's working

```
public static void flipFirstAndLast(int[] array){
for( int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
       System.out.println( " array in mathod : " +array[i]);
    System.out.println("");

    int i = array[0];
    int j = array[array.length-1];

    array[0]=j;
     array[array.length-1]=  i;
     System.out.println("after swap");
     for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
         System.out.print(array[k]);
    }

     System.out.println("");
}
```

Or you can do this also

```
 public static void flipFirstAndLast(int[] array){
    for( int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
           System.out.println( " array in mathod : " +array[i]);
        System.out.println("");

    //    int i = array[0];    //remove this line
    //    int j = array[array.length-1]; // remove this line

         int hold =0;
         hold = array[0];
         array[0] = array[array.length-1] ;
         array[array.length-1] =  hold;
         System.out.println("after swap");
         for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
             System.out.print(array[k]);
        }

         System.out.println("");
    }
```